# Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to display my reports on the browser , but I keep getting this error:

[image]

the strange thing about this, is that it only happens when I attempt to generate the reports from the version installed on the server, but not when I do it  locally from  my pc

Have you any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: What kind of server are you running?  Have you checked whether the Jasper libraries are on your server?  Sounds like your missing one.

Comment: Thank God, I left the Java world ages ago! XD

Answer (score 10):

For those still running into this issue: on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with headless OpenJDK JRE, it was simply solved by

```
apt-get install ttf-dejavu-extra
```

Answer (score 10):

This seems like a Headless mode issue. You need to set the `java.awt.headless` property to `true`. That can be done using:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
}
```

Or, by setting the headless property in your tomcat startup command as `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Answer (score 10):

For me the issue was regarding a bug in `AdoptOpenJDK`: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/682

I fixed the issue by installing `ttf-dejavu` manually in my dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-jre

# Workaround for wrong font configuration in adoptopenjdk
# https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/682
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
   && apk add --no-cache ttf-dejavu \
   # Install windows fonts as well. Not required..
   && apk add --no-cache msttcorefonts-installer \
   && update-ms-fonts && fc-cache -f
```

AND by running the application with the flag `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Answer (score 7):

This is a missing jars in the class path issue.

I had this issue and found that with by adding the missing jars to the class path it resolved the issue.

From the below article 
[java.dzone.com article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-reporting-part-2) 
I found that the minimal jars necessary are...Now The versions numbers have changed but with these libraries only I managed to get it working.

- jasperreports-2.0.4.jar
- commons-digester-1.7.jar
- commons-collections-2.1.jar (commons-collections.jar)
- commons-logging-1.0.2.jar
- commons-beanutils.jar
- iText-2.0.7.jar (used infor PDF exporting)

Answer (score 7):

This can as well be caused by missing/inaccessible Java 'temp' directory. In Font.java, temp files are being created:

```
Files.createTempFile("+~JF", ".tmp").toFile();
```

On one system, the 'temp' dir was missing under Tomcat folder but Java was configured to use it:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp
```

BTW. first time around, after restarting Tomcat, the service was actually throwing an IOException, but then JasperReports cached something and on subsequent calls the stack trace was exactly as reported here.

Comment: this answer is really helpful and works for me... thanks & upvoted :)

Answer (score 7):

I got this error while deploying springboot app (including jasper reporting) in docker container.The problem was with **openjdk:8-jdk-alpine** which I used for building docker container environment. That has a bug in fonts support. Therefore I switched to **openjdk:8-jre** (or OpenJDK 7 versions will also help) and it worked for me. *I spent days to fix this bug.*

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the issue, do the following:

1. Switched from Open JDK to Sun JDK
2. Installed MS Core Fonts
3. Packaged JasperReport font library jar with the application

Answer (score 4):

this may be problems with memory, reboot the server.

Comment: This error also occurs when the system generating the JR output is out of disk space.

Comment: @IsraelLopez That was the issue in my case

Comment: I just restarted my PC and the issue was gone. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late but couldn't resist answering this one to help out a lot of guys in trouble. After a lot of trial and error, figured out that xml-apis jar is excluded in catalina.properties of tomcat. Remove it from there and it should work. Didn't notice any side effects till now, works great.

Also, make sure the fonts are installed and check gradle/pom for merge strategy if any exclusions are made on xml-apis jar.

BTW, this problem started coming for us after upgrading to jdk11 and moving from tomcat 8 to 9.

Answer (score 1):

I searched several hours for the same issue, and my solution is none of the others mentioned.

Due to a bad update of my jasper reports version I had multiple versions of the jasperreports jar file on my classpath. Make sure you only have a single jasperreports jar file...

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but here is why we had this problem... We recently started developing with IntelliJ instead of Eclipse. We simply forgot to run IntelliJ as administrator... We had done this with Eclipse for a long time already, but simply didn't think about it with IntelliJ.
In the end, I guess the fonts weren't found or a folder was not found since there were insufficient rights to read/write on the c drive.

Comment: I was using Net Beans, and also fixed this issue by running as Administrator. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error - apparently JRStyledTextParser is using dependency from xml-apis
By adding xml-apis I got it fixed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using Arial fonts for this i have configured arial fonts in irfonts.xml
which was like below

<fontFamily name="Arial">
<normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]>
</normal>
<bold><![CDATA[fonts/arialbd.ttf]]>
</bold>
     <italic><![CDATA[fonts/ariali.ttf]]>
</italic>
<boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/arialbi.ttf]]>
</boldItalic>
<pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]>
</pdfEmbedded></fontFamily>
but it should be like : 
<fontFamily name="Arial">
<normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]><
/normal>
<bold><![CDATA[fonts/arialbd.ttf]]></bold>
<italic><![CDATA[fonts/ariali.ttf]]></italic>
<boldItalic><!
[CDATA[fonts/arialbi.ttf]]></boldItalic>
<pdfEmbedded><!
[CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
</fontFamily>
so their was a space before the end tag of each tag in above configuration file.
i fixed it by removing space between them.

Answer (score 0):

This might help ,I had the same error and every other solution didn't work.

I fixed it by updating to java8.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it helped to delete the temp server (thus making sure there are no jar duplicities) and restart server.
Hint: try this in case if the error starts occurring after a new release (but worked before and nothing relevant changed in the release)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue on my development machine. Basically it was happened due to problem in application server (**Apache tomcat**)

Basically I've accidentally deleted the "**temp**" folder in server root. So jasper cant compile the report and proceed with the report generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make a downgrade to jdk7, it's works to me.

sorry my english!

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with the jdk8 which I was using to build docker image, but after some search I switched to jre. That fixed my bug. I think you can try any image rather than using jdk8.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps to solve this problem.

1. -Djaav.awt.headless=true in startup script or vm options
2. Install the fonts

   yum install fontconfig

Then you can verify

```
rpm -qa | grep font
fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-8.el7.noarch
dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-6.el7.noarch
fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
```

This is on CentOS 7.
We had been using Google Noto fonts and thought that we do not need any font installation but was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was because I had upgraded JasperSoft Studio and thereafter new or edited reports were compiled in a newer JasperReports version and were therefore unreadable by the server. There is a compile compatibility mode in Studio, but I couldn't get it to work, and the version I was running on the server (6.6.0) wasn't listed as an option in the list of compatibility versions (and using other "close" versions didn't work either).

I ended up installing a legacy Studio version 6.6.0, and recompiled my reports in it. When I deployed the new .jasper files to the server they worked right away and all is well again.

Answer (score 0):

Using Payara (4 in my case) already has `-Djava.awt.headless=true`, We are using Jasper 6.6.0 but downgraded to 6.4.0 (for another dependency)
we had the same problem when did a fresh install of payara4 with oracle JDK 8u281, downgrading to 8u181 or 8u171 solved it

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your jasperreports-dependency.

I got a similar stacktrace, when using this outdated version of jasperreports:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This fixed my issues:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For us the problem was that we had to use the standard Openjdk version not the alpine one. I assure you that all the other fixes don't work.