# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: . .

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a report with JasperReport, when I tried it on localserver everything went well. However, when I tested on the server, the following error occurred.
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser".
The server I use is Linux OS

I want jasperReport to be successful on my server

Comment: Check this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/4998762/22414504

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: First, welcome to SO. You might want to read [ask] in order to improve your questions. Additionally, you should note that when asking about exceptions you should include the stack trace (format it nicely in a code block). Ideally also provide the version of the library you're using because there might be differences in how versions behave.